# Warning: strpos(): Offset not contained in string in

Tags: php

I have this row in a php application :

```html
 $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$baseHref = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=='localhost' ? '/byetask/' : '/';
$hasMultipleUrlParts = strpos($url, '/', strlen($baseHref)) !== false;
```

It throws an error and I dont understand why:

> Warning: strpos(): Offset not contained in string in C:\bitnami\wampstack-5.6.24-0\apache2\htdocs.....\ng-src\index.php on line 6

Have I done something wrong? Can someone explain me this? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more details like what exactly is the input, and what are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: Could you post the content of $url and $baseHref. I would hazard a guess that strlen ($baseHref) returns a value greater than $url length.

Comment: @vhoen I m editing the question

Comment: @Daniel, can you post the output of var_dump($url, $baseHref); ?

Answer (score 6):

The string `$url` is shorter than `$baseHref`, so it's trying to start the search beyond the end of the string.

Comment: A comment should prompt for (or give) more information that leads to an answer. If the comment _is_ the answer, then it should be posted as an answer

Answer (score 1):

There is issue in offset length, your offset length is greater than the actual string that's why you are getting this error.

```html
$baseHref = "http://stackoverflow.com";
//$url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/"; // URL length is greater than base URL 

$url = ""; // URL is empty or shorter than base url
if(strlen($baseHref) < strlen($url))
 $hasMultipleUrlParts = strpos($url, '/', strlen($baseHref)) !== false;
else 
 $hasMultipleUrlParts = false;

var_dump($hasMultipleUrlParts);
```

Try this code, it set $hasMultipleUrlParts to false whenever $url is shorter than $baseHref or empty.